# SQL SELECT, Displaying multi rows from many columns

Tags: php, mysql

Ok so I have information in a database I need displayed but having trouble calling it correctly.

```
ID     Name    sid         pos
-------------------------------
0      John    71829182    -30, 21, 0
1      John    71829182    -21, 21, 54
2      John    71829182    43, 21, -37
3      John    71829182    98, 21, 21
```

I need to display all rows that have the same sid row so when echoed out using php it would be like

John at 71829182 was seen in these positions -30, 21, 0 | -21, 21, 54 | 43, 21, -37 | 98, 21, 21

I can not figure it out so could use advice.

Comment: Right now I am just doing a basic query and calling on $row['pos']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're interested in a SQL solution, you can use `GROUP_CONCAT` to combine the rows into a single column:

```
SELECT name, sid, GROUP_CONCAT(pos SEPARATOR '|') positions
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY name, sid
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/080117/2)

---

Edit, given your comments, this should work:

```
SELECT playername, steamID, position, lastlogin, 
      GROUP_CONCAT(position SEPARATOR '|') positions 
FROM player 
GROUP BY playername, steamID ORDER by playername
```

Please not, in your php code, you can no longer call `row['position']` but rather should call `row['positions']` because the column name has changed.

Comment: This does not seem to work at all and give me an error. `$sql = mysql_query("SELECT playername, SteamID, position, lastlogin GROUP_CONCAT(position SEPARATOR '|') positions FROM Player GROUP BY playername, SteamID ORDER by playername");
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
  echo 'While'.$row['playername'].' was last seen in these locations '.$row['position'].'';
 }`

Comment: @JoshuaNightingale: You're missing a comma between expressions in the SELECT list, between `lastlogin` and `GROUP_CONCAT()`. And this is 2014. Why are we *still* using the mysql_ interface, and not PDO or mysqli?

Comment: You're missing a comma between lastlogin and GROUP_CONCAT. Always test if the statement succeeds with if($sql !== false)

Comment: @sgeddes: it might be worth mentioning that the length of the string returned by `GROUP_CONCAT` aggregate function is limited by the setting of the `group_concat_mex_len` variable, and less directly, by setting of the  `max_allowed_packet` variable.

Comment: Thanks working great just need to fix a few other things and ill be done this....

Answer (score 0):

You will need to fill in: YOUR_DB_SERVER, YOUR_DB_NAME, YOUR_USERNAME, YOUR_PASSWORD, YOUR_TABLE

```
$db = new PDO( 'mysql:host=YOUR_DB_SERVER;dbname=YOUR_DB_NAME;charset=UTF8', 'YOUR_USERNAME', 'YOUR_PASSWORD' );
$db->query( 'select * from YOUR_TABLE WHERE sid = YOUR_SID' );
$res = $db->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
print_r( $res );
```

This example uses PDO, which most people here will recommend you use to interface with DBs in PHP, due to its robust nature, mainly its ability to avoid SQL injection and support for many DB types. There are a number of other functions you can use to interface with DBs, but they are legacy and will not be around for much longer.

In the above example fetchAll is used to get all results; you can also use fetch() for one row and fetchColumn() for one row.

PDO::FETCH_ASSOC tells PDO to return an array with the field names bound to the field value. There are other options, see the PHP manual for details.

Comment: Also mysqli just as robust but can only connect to mysql db's